# Making stand-alone jar with Simple Build Tool

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there a way to tell sbt to package all needed libraries (scala-library.jar) into the main package, so it is stand-alone? (static?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a sbt-managed application project without sbt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195079/how-to-run-a-sbt-managed-application-project-without-sbt)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7195079/1305344 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7134993/1305344

Comment: http://blog.prabeeshk.com/blog/2014/04/01/a-standalone-spark-application-in-scala/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit 2011:
Since then, [retronym](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160378/retronym) (which posted an [answer in this page back in 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887655/making-stand-alone-jar-with-simple-build-tool/2892363#2892363)), made this [sbt-plugin "sbt-onejar"](https://github.com/retronym/sbt-onejar), now in its [**new address on GitHub**](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar), with docs updated for SBT 0.12.

> **Packages your project using [One-JAR™](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/)**
>
> `onejar-sbt` is a simple-build-tool plugin for building a single executable JAR containing all your code and dependencies as nested JARs.
> Currently One-JAR version 0.9.7 is used. This is included with the plugin, and need not be separately downloaded.

---

Original answer:

Directly, this is not possible without extending sbt (a [custom action](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/CustomActions) after the model of the ["package" sbt action](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/RunningSbt)).

[GitHub mentions an assembly task](http://wiki.github.com/alandipert/step/how-to-deploy-a-step-as-a-single-executable-jar), custom made for jetty deployment. You could adapt it for your need though.

The [code is pretty generic](http://technically.us/git?p=sling.git&a=blob&f=project/build/AssemblyProject.scala&h=2231d9c9c54b5cde7d54c52c360cc778a41e4e3e&hb=HEAD) (from [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/step-user/msg/7df47d814f12a45f), and user Rio):

```
 project / build / AssemblyProject.scala

 import sbt._
 
 trait AssemblyProject extends BasicScalaProject
 {
         def assemblyExclude(base: PathFinder) = base / "META-INF" ** "*"
         def assemblyOutputPath = outputPath / assemblyJarName
         def assemblyJarName = artifactID + "-assembly-" + version + ".jar"
         def assemblyTemporaryPath = outputPath / "assembly-libs"
         def assemblyClasspath = runClasspath
         def assemblyExtraJars = mainDependencies.scalaJars
 
         def assemblyPaths(tempDir: Path, classpath: PathFinder, extraJars: PathFinder, exclude: PathFinder => PathFinder) =
         {
                 val (libs, directories) = classpath.get.toList.partition(ClasspathUtilities.isArchive)
                 for(jar <- extraJars.get ++ libs) FileUtilities.unzip(jar, tempDir, log).left.foreach(error)
                 val base = (Path.lazyPathFinder(tempDir :: directories) ##)
                 (descendents(base, "*") --- exclude(base)).get
         }
         
         lazy val assembly = assemblyTask(assemblyTemporaryPath, assemblyClasspath, assemblyExtraJars, assemblyExclude) dependsOn(compile)
         def assemblyTask(tempDir: Path, classpath: PathFinder, extraJars: PathFinder, exclude: PathFinder => PathFinder) =
                 packageTask(Path.lazyPathFinder(assemblyPaths(tempDir, classpath, extraJars, exclude)), assemblyOutputPath, packageOptions)
 }
```

Comment: imho it should be. I've successfully used a slightly modified version of this AssemblyProject for a few months now. It will fail on duplicate files (something to watch for if you have a complex project with sub-projects), and will fail with the latest build of hibernate (hibernate includes some weird zip entries that cause it grief).

Comment: The URL to sbt-onejar has changed: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar (has new version and docs updated for SBT 0.12)

Answer (score 6):

It takes a bit of work, but you can also use [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) from within SBT to create a standalone JAR.

I did this recently in the [SBT build for Scalala](http://github.com/scalala/Scalala/tree/master/project/).

Comment: Proguard is powerful, but if you have a lot of jars, you have to manually define every class or method called dynamically  - see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/limitations.html and see "problems at runtime" http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/troubleshooting.html

Comment: https://github.com/ymasory/sbt-prototype uses [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) to make an executable jar. The prototype works out-of-the-box flawlessly at least on a simple applications.

Answer (score 0):

Working off of what @retronym offered above, I built a [simple example](https://github.com/leifwickland/pathetic-attempts-to-investigate-hbase/tree/master/helloWorldProguard) that builds a stand alone jar which includes the Scala libraries (i.e. scala-library.jar) using Proguard with sbt.  Thanks, retronym.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest example using [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly)

1. Create directory project in your home project dir with file assembly.sbt including

   addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")
2. In file build.sbt

   import AssemblyKeys._ // put this at the top of the file

   assemblySettings

   jarName += "Mmyjarnameall.jar"

   libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "exmpleofmydependency % "mydep" % "0.1" )

   mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>

   {

   case s if s.endsWith(".class") => MergeStrategy.last

   case s if s.endsWith("pom.xml") => MergeStrategy.last

   case s if s.endsWith("pom.properties") => MergeStrategy.last

   case x => old(x)

   }

   }

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is just to create the jar from the command line. If you don't know how to do this I would highly recommend that you do so. Automation is useful, but its much better if you know what the automation is doing.

The easiest way to automate the creation of a runnable jar is to use a bash script or batch script in windows.

The simplest way in sbt is just to add the Scala libraries you need to the resource directories:

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile := Seq(file("/sdat/bins/ScalaCurrent/lib/scalaClasses"))
```

So in my environment ScalaCurrent is a link to the current Scala library. 2.11.4 at the time of writing. The key point is that I extract the Scala library but place it inside a ScalaClassses directory. Each extracted library needs to go into its top level directory.