# Scala SBT: standalone jar

Tags: scala, package, executable-jar, sbt

The answer: [Making stand-alone jar with Simple Build Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2887655/244526) seems like what I need, but it did not have enough information for me, so this is a followup.

(1) How do I adapt the answer to my need? I don't understand what would need to be changed.

(2) What command do I run to create the standalone jar?

(3) Where can I find the jar after it has been created?

---

What I've tried:

- Pasting the code in the linked answer verbatim into my: `project/build/dsg.scala` file. The file now has a

  `class ForkRun(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultProject(info)`

  (from before, used for running projects in a separate VM from SBT) and the new:

  `trait AssemblyProject extends BasicScalaProject`

  from the linked answer.
- I also tried pasting the body (all `defs` and the `lazy val` of the `AssemblyProject` into the body of `ForkRun`.

To create a `jar` I ran `package` at the SBT prompt and get:

```
[info] Packaging ./target/scala_2.8.1/dsg_2.8.1-1.0.jar ...
[info] Packaging complete.
```

So I tried running the `dsg_2.8.1-1.0.jar` from the shell via:

```
java -jar dsg_2.8.1-1.0.jar
```

But I get:

```
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
dsg_2.8.1-1.0.jar
```

Could this be caused by having multiple entry points into my project? I select from a list when I execute `run` from the SBT prompt. Perhaps I need to specify the default when creating the package?

Comment: I have edited my answer from 2010 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887655/making-stand-alone-jar-with-simple-build-tool/2887681#2887681) to include retronym's sbt-onejar plugin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run an sbt main class from the shell as normal command-line program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134993/how-do-i-run-an-sbt-main-class-from-the-shell-as-normal-command-line-program)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7134993/1305344 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7195079/1305344

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a writeup I did on one way to make an executable jar with SBT:

http://janxspirit.blogspot.com/2011/01/create-executable-scala-jar-with-sbt.html

Comment: Thanks. Turns out that I was not: (1) setting the default entry point via `override def mainClass: Option[String] = Some("Test")` (2) running the `assembly` task (instead of `package`) and (3) running the wrong executable, the correct one is `target/scala_2.8.1/dsg_2.8.1-assembly-1.0.jar`

Answer (score 1):

**sbt-assembly** is a sbt plugin to create a standalone jar of Scala sbt project with all of its dependencies.

Refer [this post](http://blog.prabeeshk.com/blog/2014/04/08/creating-uber-jar-for-spark-project-using-sbt-assembly/) for more details with an example.