# How do I run an sbt main class from the shell as normal command-line program?

Tags: scala, classpath, sbt

How can I run an sbt app from the shell, so that I can run my app as a normal command-line program (as if run directly via `scala` but without having to set up an enormous classpath)?

I know I can do:

```
echo hello | sbt 'run-main com.foo.MyMain3 arg1 arg2' > out.txt
```

But this (1) takes forever to start because it starts sbt, (2) causes all stdout and stderr to go to stdout, and (3) causes all output to be decorated with a logger [info] or [error].

I looked at https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Launcher but it seems too heavyweight, since it downloads dependencies and sets up a new environment and whatnot. I just want to run this app within my existing development environment.

Thus far I've cobbled together my own script to build up a classpath, and you can also do some other things like [modify your project file to get sbt to print the raw classpath](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/0rhVRPnjyZU), but I feel like there must be a better way.

Comment: like `mvn exec:java` or `mvn appassembler:assemble`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [start-script SBT plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script) is now at:

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script

It requires a few steps to set up and generates scripts that do not work on OS X, but that can be easily fixed if you're on that platform (see below).

## Setup

1. Install greadlink (OS X only):

   a) `brew install coreutils`

   b) map readlink to the new function (**g**readlink) by adding these lines to ~/.bashrc:

   function readlink() { greadlink "$@"; }

   export -f readlink`
2. Add start-script plugin to ~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt:

   addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-start-script" % "0.8.0")
3. Add start-script task to current project:

   `$ sbt add-start-script-tasks` # execute from directory where build.sbt resides
4. Add start-script support to current build.sbt:

   import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtStartScript

   seq(SbtStartScript.startScriptForClassesSettings: _*)

Note the blank line in between statements (de rigueur for SBT build files).

## Generate Start Script

Then, whenever you want to create a script to start your app like `sbt run-main`, but without sbt, execute:

```
$ sbt start-script
```

## Run

```
target/start mypackage.MyMainClass
```

Comment: That plugin is great but at the top of their github they very fairly say _Consider sbt-native-packager instead_

Comment: @tksfz Yes, things have changed for the better... SBT Native Packager is great.

Answer (score 18):

Here's what I have in my SBT (version 0.10) project definition,

```
  val Mklauncher = config("mklauncher") extend(Compile)
  val mklauncher = TaskKey[Unit]("mklauncher")
  val mklauncherTask = mklauncher <<= (target, fullClasspath in Runtime) map { (target, cp) =>
    def writeFile(file: File, str: String) {
      val writer = new PrintWriter(file)
      writer.println(str)
      writer.close()
    }
    val cpString = cp.map(_.data).mkString(":")
    val launchString = """
CLASSPATH="%s"
scala -usejavacp -Djava.class.path="${CLASSPATH}" "$@"
""".format(cpString)
    val targetFile = (target / "scala-sbt").asFile
    writeFile(targetFile, launchString)
    targetFile.setExecutable(true)
  }

  ... // remember to add mklauncherTask to Project Settings
```

The `mklauncher` task creates a script `target/scala-sbt` that executes `scala` with the project classpath already set. It would be nice to have `mklauncher` executed automatically whenever the classpath changes, but I haven't looked into doing this yet.

(I use the Java classpath, rather than Scala's, for ease of creating embedded interpreters.)

Comment: When you finish with making mklauncher rebuild whenever the classpath changes (say, this night? ;-), turn it into a plugin, send it to github, and put it in the sbt plugins page, ok?

Comment: Bump for Daniel's request ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Time flies by and a lot have changed since the other answers. It's currently SBT `0.13.6` time.

I think what you may need is [the sbt-onejar plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar) or [the SBT Native Packager plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager).

**sbt-onejar** *"is a simple-build-tool plugin for building a single executable JAR containing all your code and dependencies as nested JARs."*

**SBT Native Packager**'s *"goal is to be able to bundle up Scala software built with SBT for native packaging systems, like deb, rpm, homebrew, msi."*

Comment: sbt native packager looks like the more maintained out of the two (?). http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/GettingStartedApplications/MyFirstProject.html gets you going relatively quickly in my humble experience.

Answer (score 2):

Just discovered the sbt start script plugin: https://github.com/typesafehub/xsbt-start-script-plugin:

> This plugin allows you to generate a script target/start for a
>   project. The script will run the project "in-place" (without having to
>   build a package first).
>
> The target/start script is similar to sbt run but it doesn't rely on
>   SBT. sbt run is not recommended for production use because it keeps
>   SBT itself in-memory. target/start is intended to run an app in
>   production.
>
> The plugin adds a task start-script which generates target/start. It
>   also adds a stage task, aliased to the start-script task.