# Dependencies with ensime using type sbt

Tags: scala, emacs, ensime

got the following in my build.sbt:

```
name := "Ledger Accounting"

libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.8" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest" % "1.3" % "test"
```

This in my .ensime, same directory:

```
:use-sbt t
:project-package "uk.co.mydomain.ledger"
```

Using sbt I can compile the above and test a class which imports scalatest classes, however in emacs ensime cannot see anything in libraryDependencies.

Any ideas on how to make ensime pick up my build.sbt and add scalatest to my classpath? Ideally something that doesn't require me managing two lists of the same dependencies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's being worked on. See the [comments on issue 157](https://github.com/aemoncannon/ensime/issues/157) in the Github project. Two relevant quotes:

> I'm currently working on what I hope will be a comprehensive solution
>   for sbt - using expectj to talk to the running sbt process. Should
>   support 0.7 and 0.9 - 0.10 -- feel free to check out the branch (only
>   supports 0.7) right now.
>   - *aemoncannon* (the branch is [sbt-revamp](https://github.com/aemoncannon/ensime/tree/sbt-revamp))

and,

> I have implemented a simple version of idea 3 of mathiask as a stopgap
>   measure to get something sort of working with the current ensime, in
>   case anyone needs something before the final solution is ready:
>   https://github.com/fhars/sbt-ensime-plugin
>   - *fhars*

I suggest trying fhars' plugin to generate the `.ensime` file. You could also write your own SBT task to output the classpath; I have a [variation of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134993/how-do-i-run-an-sbt-main-class-from-the-shell-as-normal-command-line-program/7135161#7135161) in my SBT project definition.

Comment: Kipton - thanks so much for this. Now I can carry on learning scala and enjoying the fun functions and ensime. A big thanks!