# How to run a sbt-managed application project without sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

My question is about running an application that's in a project managed by sbt `0.10.1` and hence relies on its automatic dependency management (to download and set up appropriate classpath to run).

When using the automatic dependency management, it **appears** that the only way to run the application is using sbt itself because it knows how to set up the classpath (with a help of Ivy2).

How can I run the application without sbt?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also use Typesafe's <s>xsbt-start-script-plugin</s> (edit: now [sbt-start-script](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script)) to generate a shell script with the correct class path:

> This plugin allows you to generate a script `target/start` for a
>   project.  The script will run the project "in-place" (without having
>   to build a package first).
>
> The `target/start` script is similar to `sbt run` but it doesn't rely
>   on SBT. `sbt run` is not recommended for production use because it
>   keeps SBT itself in-memory. `target/start` is intended to run an
>   app in production.
>
> The plugin adds a task `start-script` which generates `target/start`.
>   It also adds a `stage` task, aliased to the `start-script` task.

This is what [Heroku uses](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scala) to run Scala apps.

Comment: Hello Ben, maybe you have an hint for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607291/run-a-sbt-created-app-without-sbt) ? A full example of `sbt-start-script` would really be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [retronym](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160378/retronym)'s [sbt-onejar plugin](https://github.com/retronym/sbt-onejar) to create executable jars with all dependencies included (much like the [Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) for Maven). It's very simple and well documented.

Comment: +1 retronym plugin looks better than the one I suggested, as it does not unpack the dependencies

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a 'fat' jar containing all your application and your dependencies, you can use the [sbt-assembly plugin](https://github.com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly). Then you can run your application as a standard `jar` without sbt.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a task to create a file to launch the app. @Kipton Barros posted this in [How do I run an sbt main class from the shell as normal command-line program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134993/how-do-i-run-an-sbt-main-class-from-the-shell-as-normal-command-line-program):

```
  val MkUnixlauncher = config("mkunixlauncher") extend(Compile)
  val mkunixlauncher = TaskKey[Unit]("mkunixlauncher")
  val mkunixlauncherTask = mkunixlauncher <<= (target, fullClasspath in Runtime) map { (target, cp) =>
    def writeFile(file: File, str: String) {
      val writer = new PrintWriter(file)
      writer.println(str)
      writer.close()
    }
    val cpString = cp.map(_.data).mkString(System.getProperty("path.separator"))
    val launchString = """
CLASSPATH="%s"
scala -usejavacp -Djava.class.path="${CLASSPATH}" "$@"
""".format(cpString)
    val targetFile = (target / "scala-sbt").asFile
    writeFile(targetFile, launchString)
    targetFile.setExecutable(true)
  }
```

That creates a file named scala-sbt in your target directory that has the classpath set properly to run the app. Tweak to taste.

Comment: This comes closest to what I was looking to achieve.