# Run a sbt-created app without sbt

Tags: java, scala, jar, sbt, typesafe-stack

This is somehow a follow-up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195079/how-to-run-a-sbt-managed-application-project-without-sbt).

When I'm creating a Scala package with sbt, I am able to run it using one of these ways:

- simply by typing `run` in the sbt console
- or by creating a jar file (using either `one-jar` or `assembly`), and the running this jar in the system console by typing `java -jar myjar.jar`

But I don't know how to

- *run my package from the scala program ? (not the sbt scala console, in which everything works fine by typing `import mypackage._`)*
- *use my Scala package in another project ? for example by importing `myjar` in another project ?*

---

**EDIT** : you can forget my questions below about `sbt-start-script` because now I'm using [`sbt-native-packager`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager) (I have tried it just now and it works, but my previous questions remain open).

---

I have tried to use [sbt-start-script](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script) but unsucessfully. The `target/start` script is well created but I get such errors:

```
$ sh target/start
target/start: 2: target/start: Bad substitution
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hi
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Hi
...
```

Here I simply have a `main.scala` file in the `src/main/scala` folder and it is:

```
object Hi { def main(args: Array[String]) = println("Hi!") }
```

I'm using these settings in `build.sbt` :

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtStartScript

seq(SbtStartScript.startScriptForClassesSettings: _*)
```

Comment: Just to clarify: what you want to do is to use your library as a dependency in another SBT project?

Comment: @lpiepiora I think I get it now. For the scala console, add the jar in the classpath. For another SBT project, add the jar in the lib folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways how you can use your project in another project. I will not discus the publishing to remote repository, as that's probably something you don't want to do anyway (at least at this point in time).

Lets assume you have a project called *projectA* - the `build.sbt` is just this:

```
name := "project-a"

organization := "com.acme"

version := "0.1.0"
```

And you have another project called *projectB*, where you want to use classes defined in *projectA*.

## Unmanaged Dependency

One of the simplest ways is to use it as a [unmanaged dependency](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html#unmanaged-dependencies). You can do that by putting the `jar` file produced by `package`, `assembly` or any other command producing an artefact.

## Local Repository

Another way to use your dependency is to publish it to your local repository. Given the *projectA* as defined above, to the `build.sbt` of a *projectB*, add a dependency

```
libraryDependencies += "com.acme" %% "project-a" % "0.1.0"
```

Now you can publish *projectA* to your local repository by executing `publishLocal` in the *projectA*. The advantage of this approach is that if your *projectA* declares any dependencies, they will be added as transitive dependencies to *projectB*.

## Project Dependency

Last way that comes to my mind is to declare dependency directly on the *projectA*. You can do that by creating a `build.sbt` file in the *projectB*, which looks more or less like this

```
lazy val projectA = file("/home/lpiepiora/q-23607291/projectA")

lazy val projectB = project in file(".") dependsOn projectA
```

Now classes declared in *projectA* should be visible in *projectB*.

Comment: Great explanations. Since I have found myself the answers to my other questions (see my comment below the OP), I click for your answer.