# Howto create a .jar including both sources (.java and .scala) and classes with sbt?

Tags: scala, class, jar, sbt

I would like `sbt package` or any variant to produce a '.jar' from my project that would include also the sources ('.java' and '.scala' files).

This would be a mix of packageBin and packageSrc.

I did not:

- find any task that would do this?
- find how to adapt package task
- nor define a new task of mine to achieve this

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala SBT: standalone jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026149/scala-sbt-standalone-jar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Package.html#Modify+the+contents+of+the+package), you should probably add stuff to the `mappings` key in the `packageBin` scope. The following seems to work for me:

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ++= (mappings in (Compile, packageSrc)).value
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to setup a standalone task for creating an artifact with binaries and sources, leaving `packageBin` and `packageSrc` unaffected:

```
val packageBinSrc = taskKey[File]("Produces an artifact containing both binaries and sources.")

artifactClassifier in packageBinSrc := Some("binsrc")
inConfig(Compile) {
  import Defaults._
  packageTaskSettings(packageBinSrc, concatMappings(packageBinMappings, packageSrcMappings))
}
```

Optionally, if you fancy, you can redefine `package` to use `packageBinSrc`:

```
Keys.`package` := (packageBinSrc in Compile).value
```

Comment: Since there were two questions in one, both answers are of interest for me. Unfortunately, I have to mark one as "best". I chosed the shortest…

Great thanks for those answers

Comment: I'd argue you're breaking the intent of `packageBin` by adding sources to it, but it is less setup code to be sure.