# Converting a Scala library to a DLL (.NET)

Tags: java, scala, dll, ikvm

I'm trying to create a Dll out of a scala-class. I'm using IntelliJ together with SBT. I've already found a way to convert .jar files into a Dll, using the ikvm-converter. Now the problem: When I use "package" under SBT to create a .jar file out of my .scala file and try to convert it afterwards with ikvmc into a Dll the resulting library is empty when integrated in C#...

For example converting the Jama-Library (which is written in Java) works fine, where converting Scama (written in Scala) does not work.

Is there a way to do this conversion of scala code into a dll? Is there a "Scala to Java"-conversion tool?

Best Regards,
Christoph

Comment: Are you including your scala runtime jars into your conversion as well? Please show your ikvmc command line.

Comment: Scala compiles to Java bytecode, so there is no reason Scala itself poses some problems with IKVMC. When you compile Scala, you get a Java Class. It looks like the problem is that Scama API has not the right visibility rules to be accessible from C# when converted through IKVM

Comment: ikvmc -target:library jama-1.0.2.jar

Comment: ikvmc -target:library scama_2.9.0-1.0.jar This gives me to .dll files. When converting the scama library, I get warnings, when converting Jama I do not get warnings.

Comment: Try converting this jar alongside with all of the dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

I have no knowledge of .NET, but judging from SK-logic's and your comments to the questions: `sbt package` does *not* include the Scala runtime library, because it assumes you are going to export your project as a library to be used within other Scala projects.

Therefore, you will need to create a "fat" jar that contains the runtime. For example, in [this blog](http://tountas-software.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/scala-on-net-via-ikvm.html) you can see how the author creates a fully self-contained executable, by converting both the project jar and the runtime jar.

There are different tools to do that with sbt. The easiest would be [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly), but you will end up with a very large file, because it just adds the whole runtime. If that is a problem, you may want to filter the runtime instead, using the [proguard plugin](https://github.com/nuttycom/sbt-proguard-plugin). More on this topic in [another StackOverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887655/making-stand-alone-jar-with-simple-build-tool).

Comment: Not necessarily one fat jar, you can process a number of jars simultaneously (and it is a recommended way of using ikvmc).