# Scala service on windows

Tags: windows, scala, service

I am able to compile my application to a single jar using [sbt and one-jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2887681/1287856), and I am aware of the existence of [JavaExe](http://en.kioskea.net/download/download-1634-javaexe) and [JavaService](http://forge.ow2.org/projects/javaservice/), although I don't know yet how to use them.

Is there any tool which would transform a jar to a service in Windows? I would like to be able to call an executable to "talk" to my running application rather than having to start it from scratch every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp) is your friend here :)